# Ionic 2 - Infinite Scroll on Large Screens

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a page with infinite scroll at the bottom and it is working well but the issue is that the app is meant for browsers also. On browsers, the first paginated result taking almost 50% of the page, and hence the infinite scroll is not working unless I resize down the browser and make it scroll down.

How can I fix this issue?